# Values are not getting inserted into the PostgreSQL database

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have made a database on pgAdmin 4 but values are not updated when sent through signup form on node.also npm install postgre-sql giving an error

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    const { Pool,Client} = require('pg')

    const connectionString='postgressql://postgres:12345@@localhost:5432/postgres'
    const client= new Client({
      connectionString:connectionString
    })

    client.connect()
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });
    router.post('/action',function(req,res){
      var uname= req.query.username;
      var pass= req.query.psw;
      var em= req.query.email;
      var DOB=req.query.dob;
      var gen= req.query.gender;

      client.query('INSERT INTO SIGNUP(username,email,password,DOB,gender) VALUES ("'+uname+'", "'+em+'", "'+pass+'","'+DOB+'","'+gen+'")',(err,res)=>{
        console.log(err,res)
        client.end()
      } )
    })
    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a typo there
**postgressql**://postgres:12345@@localhost:5432/postgres

should be **postgresql**://postgres:12345@@localhost:5432/postgres